# Subdivide raster file by polygon in R

Tags: raster, r, spatial-join, sp

I am trying to get a raster file of nightlights data for Brazil and subdivide/regroup it into several rasters for each state, in a list or data.frame in R

I managed to download the nightlights file, import into R using the `raster` package, and crop it for a bounding box of Brazil. Reproducible code:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(R.utils)
library(raster)

#Source: 'https://ngdc.noaa.gov/eog/data/web_data/v4composites/F182013.v4.tar'  
#Download this file manually ( untar() command does not work if I use download.file() to download)
fo <- 'C:/.../NightLights/'
f <- list.files(fo,full.names = T)
untar(f,exdir = fo)
tif <- paste0(fo,'/F182013.v4c_web.stable_lights.avg_vis.tif')
gunzip(paste0(tif,'.gz'),tif )

bra = getData('GADM', country="BRA", level=0) #country division
bra1 = getData('GADM', country="BRA", level=1) #state disions

F18_bra <- raster(tif) %>% crop(bra) #imports raster for a Bunding Box of Brazil
```

As the above code indicates I also imported the polygons for Brazilian states (object `bra1`)

I want to do a spatial join of the raster and the state polygons.

In the end, I want a data.frame, or list, with: `state_id`, `state_raster`. I.e., one line/element per state, with a raster object with the pixels inside the polygon of each state on each cell of `state_raster` (like a bucket or geom in Postgis)

Can I do this in R, preferably using the `sp`, `sf` and/or `raster` packages?

Comment: I suspect you want to `rasterize()` the polygon with some ID variable and that gives you a raster like `F18_bra` but with polygon ID values. You can then apply any function grouped over those ID values on the `F18_bra` raster. If you can make a reproducible example (maybe generate a fake "lights" raster of similar scale) and that doesn't use `library(tidyverse)` I'll write a full answer for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use the combination of the `crop()` and `mask()` functions to crop the part of your raster that lies within each of the polygons of your `bra1` object. Then, you might use `lapply()` to "loop over" all states to obtain a list, as you desired. Make sure to have both objects at the same `CRS`:

```
bra1 <- spTransform(bra1, tif@crs)
output <- lapply(1:nrow(bra1), function(x) {
  list(state_id = x, state_raster = mask(crop(tif,bra1[x,]), bra1[x,]))
})
```

The output, with a polygon and raster of mine, is a list as you desired:

```
> output
[[1]]
[[1]]$state_id
[1] 1

[[1]]$state_raster
class       : RasterLayer 
dimensions  : 52, 75, 3900  (nrow, ncol, ncell)
resolution  : 0.08333333, 0.08333333  (x, y)
extent      : -17.58333, -11.33333, 12.33333, 16.66667  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
coord. ref. : +proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +no_defs +ellps=WGS84 +towgs84=0,0,0 
data source : in memory
names       : act2000_r_mze_2000_har 
values      : 0, 0.3313416  (min, max)



[[2]]
[[2]]$state_id
[1] 2

[[2]]$state_raster
class       : RasterLayer 
dimensions  : 151, 147, 22197  (nrow, ncol, ncell)
resolution  : 0.08333333, 0.08333333  (x, y)
extent      : -17.08333, -4.833333, 14.75, 27.33333  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
coord. ref. : +proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +no_defs +ellps=WGS84 +towgs84=0,0,0 
data source : in memory
names       : act2000_r_mze_2000_har 
values      : 0, 0.2182628  (min, max)
```

Comment: HI @Bruno Conte Leite, I think your solution is very concise and straightforward. I am trying to adapt it to solve a similar problem (kindly see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61379579/looping-raster-package-functions-over-each-multi-polygon-feature-in-r) but have been unsuccessful. Could you offer any advice?